# getting Duplicate columns in sql inner joint query in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

please find my below code and tables where i would like to use sql query of inner joint, but with the help of my below VBA code i am getting duplication of inner joint column(i.e. Sr column) in my output.

Please guide how can i keep my inner joint columns unique in my output data.

Please note i specifically used * in select query, because instead of Sr column header the other columns header will be change every time.

My 1st table-

[image]

My 2nd table-

[image]

My output-

[image]

```
Sub SQL()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet3$] INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet2$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Sr]"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheet5.Range("D1").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You get exactly what you asked for. All fields from the first table and all from the other  one. Will you change number and names of columns every time in both tables? Maybe reconsider your project that the first table is always comprised of fixed number of columns. Then, the SQL string would be:

```
SELECT [Sheet2$].[Code], [Sheet3$].* 
FROM [Sheet3$] INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet2$].[Sr]=[Sheet3$].[Sr]
```

UPDATE:
If you must use all columns from both table, you can remove additiona Sr after running SQL. If you want remove the first one, just use:

```
Sub RemoveFirstSr()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do Until Cells(1, i).Value = "Sr"
    i = i + 1
Loop
Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

For the second:

```
Sub RemoveSecondSr()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For j = 0 To 1
i = 1
Do Until Cells(1, i).Value = "Sr"
    i = i + 1
Loop
i = i + 1
Next j
Cells(1, i - 1).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

If the output looks like you have showed in your question, everything shall be OK. But you may add some additional code to avoid infinite loop inside (for i next):

```
If i = 16383 Then
    MsgBox "Infinite loop!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Just for any case.

Comment: No Sir in both the table except **Sr** columns all other column name's will be change or any other new columns will also added in both the table.

Comment: This is bad design for me, but please check my edited answer.